# Find values which are not present in the table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 7 different kind of components which starts from **APC,BPC,CPC,DPC,FPC,LPC,MPC** and they are attached to a ParentPart. In some cases there are three components(of two kinds) are attached to a parent part, in other 5 etc.  From the table given below I would like to find out what components are in the parent parts and what are not in the parent part.

**Code for the table (to help the users so that they can easily put it in fiddle or somewhere:**

```
CREATE TABLE #test(
PARENTPART varchar(20),
ParentDescription varchar(15),
Component varchar(15),
Altkey varchar(20),
Qty int,
)

INSERT INTO #test
VALUES ('APF.20.015.09','Person Comp','APC2032','000123',1),
('APF.20.015.09','Person Comp','APC2038','000223',1),
('APF.20.015.09','Person Comp','CPC3042','000103',1),
('APF.20.015.09','Person Comp','DPC4032','000124',1),
('APF.20.019.09','Laptop','LPC2039','000123',1),
('APF.20.019.09','Laptop','FPC2034','0001L3',1),
('APF.20.019.09','Laptop','FPC1092','0001K3',1),
('APF.20.019.09','Laptop','CPCL032','0001M3',1);

--Below is the table generated from the above code.

PARENTPART   |  ParentDescr|  Component| AltKey   |Qty|
APF.20.015.09|  Person Comp|    APC2032|    000123| 1 |
APF.20.015.09|  Person Comp|    APC2038|    000223| 1 |
APF.20.015.09|  Person Comp|    CPC3042|    000103| 1 |
APF.20.015.09|  Person Comp|    DPC4032|    000124| 1 |
APF.20.019.09|  Laptop     |    LPC2039|    000123| 1 |
APF.20.019.09|  Laptop     |    FPC2034|    0001L3| 1 |
APF.20.019.09|  Laptop     |    FPC1092|    0001K3| 1 |
APF.20.019.09|  Laptop     |    CPCL032|    0001M3| 1 |
```

I have tried the below query on the above table but it only gives me the result about the present component parts.

```
SELECT *,(CASE WHEN Component LIKE 'APC%' OR Component LIKE 'BPC%' OR Component LIKE 'CPC%' OR Component LIKE 'DPC%' OR Component LIKE 'FPC%'
OR Component LIKE 'LPC%' OR Component LIKE 'MPC%' THEN 'PRESENT' ELSE NULL END) as C FROM #test;
```

I would like the following output:

```
PARENTPART   |  ParentDescr|  Component| AltKey   |Qty  |
APF.20.015.09|  Person Comp|    APC2032|    000123| 1   |
APF.20.015.09|  Person Comp|    APC2038|    000223| 1   |
APF.20.015.09|  Person Comp|    CPC3042|    000103| 1   |
APF.20.015.09|  Person Comp|    DPC4032|    000124| 1   |
APF.20.015.09|  Person Comp|    BPC    |    NULL  | NULL|
APF.20.015.09|  Person Comp|    FPC    |    NULL  | NULL|
APF.20.015.09|  Person Comp|    MPC    |    NULL  | NULL|
APF.20.015.09|  Person Comp|    LPC    |    NULL  | NULL|
APF.20.019.09|  Laptop     |    LPC2039|    000123| 1   |
APF.20.019.09|  Laptop     |    FPC2034|    0001L3| 1   | 
APF.20.019.09|  Laptop     |    FPC1092|    0001K3| 1   |
APF.20.019.09|  Laptop     |    CPCL032|    0001M3| 1   |
APF.20.019.09|  Laptop     |    APC    |    NULL  | NULL|
APF.20.019.09|  Laptop     |    BPC    |    NULL  | NULL|
APF.20.019.09|  Laptop     |    DPC    |    NULL  | NULL|
APF.20.019.09|  Laptop     |    MPC    |    NULL  | NULL|
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `cross join` to generate the rows -- one for the parents and one for the parts.  Then use `left join` to bring in the data:

```
select p.parentpart, p.parentdescription,
       c.component, t.altkey, t.qty
from (select distinct parentpart, parentdescription
      from #test
     ) p cross join
     (select distinct component
      from #test
     ) c left join
     #test t
     on t.parentpart = p.parentpart and t.component = c.component;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e60e57652da6581977849a8d762f6c3c) is a db<>fiddle.

Here is a version that returns the abbreviated component names:

```
select p.parentpart, p.parentdescription,
       coalesce(t.component, c.component_3) as component,
       t.altkey, t.qty
from (select distinct parentpart, parentdescription
      from test
     ) p cross join
     (select v.component_3
      from (values ('APC'), ('BPC'), ('CPC'), ('DPC'), ('FPC'), ('LPC'), ('MPC')) v(component_3)
     ) c left join
     test t
     on t.parentpart = p.parentpart and left(t.component, 3) = c.component_3
order by parentpart, parentdescription, component;
```

And the corresponding [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b657b22d2a0265405f6e2ddb6f53d672).

Comment: @KartikeyaSharma Have you tried this code? It does not return your expected result. I do not understand why you accept this answer.

Comment: @GenWan . . . Thank you for pointing that out.  I fixed the answer.

Comment: @GenWan Yes i did try this code and yes it didn't exactly answered my questions but after making a bit changes I was able to get the answer I was looking for. Your answer was great to but then I didn't really understand that why you were using the table variable on the first place, can't you have just make a new temp table or maybe self join

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question.
I used 'table variable':

```
declare @table table
(ParentPart varchar(50),
 ParentDescr varchar(30),
 Component varchar(10))

insert into @table values ('APF.20.015.09','Person Comp','APC')
insert into @table values ('APF.20.015.09','Person Comp','BPC')
insert into @table values ('APF.20.015.09','Person Comp','CPC')
insert into @table values ('APF.20.015.09','Person Comp','DPC')
insert into @table values ('APF.20.015.09','Person Comp','FPC')
insert into @table values ('APF.20.015.09','Person Comp','LPC')
insert into @table values ('APF.20.015.09','Person Comp','MPC')
insert into @table values ('APF.20.019.09','laptop','APC')
insert into @table values ('APF.20.019.09','laptop','BPC')
insert into @table values ('APF.20.019.09','laptop','CPC')
insert into @table values ('APF.20.019.09','laptop','DPC')
insert into @table values ('APF.20.019.09','laptop','FPC')
insert into @table values ('APF.20.019.09','laptop','LPC')
insert into @table values ('APF.20.019.09','laptop','MPC')

SELECT 
T2.PARENTPART,T2.ParentDescr,
CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(T1.Component,1,3) = t2.Component THEN T1.Component
ELSE T2.Component
END AS COMPONENT, T1.Altkey,T1.Qty
FROM #TEST T1
RIGHT JOIN @table T2
ON T1.PARENTPART = T2.ParentPart
AND T1.ParentDescription = T2.ParentDescr
AND SUBSTRING(T1.Component,1,3) = t2.Component
```

Use 'order by' as you want.